# a button to close all opened accordion Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want to ask how to make a button to closing all opened accordion (Still toggle). The button function just to close when one of the accordion is opened. Maybe it's something weird, where the accordion has a toggle already. but in my case I need an external button to closing an opened accordion item.

I hope I can find the answer here, Thank You!

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container py-3">
<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>

    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button Close</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add hide method `collapse('hide')` [Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/collapse/#collapsehide)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn-close").on('click', function () {
     $('.collapse').collapse('hide')
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/moafbcn5/6/

Answer (score 0):

dHTML:

```
<div class="text-right">
<button class="btn close-button">
Close
</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".close-button").on('click', function () {
   $('#accordionExample').find('.card .collapse').removeClass('show'); /* this closes the opened accorion */
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the according will do below things:

Using class `.collapse` to hide content

Using `.collapse.show` to show content

What you need to do is to remove the `show` class for the expanded accordings when user clicked the close button.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".close-button").on('click', function() {
    $('#accordionExample').find('.card .collapse.show').removeClass('show'); /* this closes the opened accorion */
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ramseyfeng/0kstrbd7/

Comment: I think we have same answers.

Comment: Using method collapse('hide') is more smooth when closing a collapse item. But by the way it's the same function, Thank you so much!

Comment: @Acasisme Agree!

Answer (score 0):

**For Bootstrap 5**

The existing answers close the panel, but the chevron icon does not change orientation. This is my proposal.
***Note:*** run the code snippet below to see this working.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Look for the open panel and get the id.
    const id = $(".collapse.show").attr('id');
    if (id) {
      // Click on the element pointing to this id.
      $("[data-bs-target='#" + id + "']").click();
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn-close").on('click', function() {
    const id = $(".collapse.show").attr('id');
    if (id) {
      $("[data-bs-target='#" + id + "']").click();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example">

  <!-- Example Code -->

  <a id="btn-close" class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Button Close</a>

  <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
        <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Accordion Item #1
              </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <strong>This is the first item's accordion body.</strong> It is shown by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
          and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit
          overflow.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingTwo">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                Accordion Item #2
              </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <strong>This is the second item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
          and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit
          overflow.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingThree">
        <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                Accordion Item #3
              </button>
      </h2>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-body">
          <strong>This is the third item's accordion body.</strong> It is hidden by default, until the collapse plugin adds the appropriate classes that we use to style each element. These classes control the overall appearance, as well as the showing
          and hiding via CSS transitions. You can modify any of this with custom CSS or overriding our default variables. It's also worth noting that just about any HTML can go within the <code>.accordion-body</code>, though the transition does limit
          overflow.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```